# jQuery is adding a dynamic attribute to HTML elements

Tags: jquery

I observed that jQuery is adding attribute like jQuery17105484855763578391="21" to HTML elements. This i'm able to see only in IE but not in other browsers. Why jQuery is adding this attribute and why this is not happening in other browsers? is it using this for identifying elements on the page? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any other plugins running?

Comment: using jQuery.min.js. This u can observe for the current page as well.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963335/893780